# Can an ASP.NET MVC3 Controller (and View?) be redistributed as a class library dll?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, class-library, reusability

is it possible to add a single Controller and possibly a view or two, in a class library ... which could then be redistributed (ie. via NuGet) and reused in various applications?

I'm thinking of providing a default view (or two) but allowing the consumer to override this view via a public property.

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built-in ASP.NET MVC 3 allowing you to embed views into class libraries (controllers, yes, but not views). It is necessary to write a custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx). Here's a [blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/#axzz1E3KVZXqS) which might put you on the right track. And you could also take a look at [MVCContrib portable areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) which allows you to do this.

Comment: How about defining a route, to a controller .. where the controller exists in a referenced class library? Lets assume that the view is not embedded in the class library and is defined via properties.

Comment: @Pure.Krome, having a controller which resides in a different assembly is possible. Just define a controller in a separate assembly, reference this assembly in your web application and it should work.